# HP Envy Touchpad/Trackpad/Mousead glitching after updating from Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: 14.04, mouse, touchpad, hp, trackpad

So, windows refugee and my first new computer in...about a decade.  Fair warning.

Touchpad was fine at first, then I did the prompted updates.  I also tried to install the beta of scrivener, it didn't work and wouldn't open.  The touchpad got glitchy, so I find the psmouse fix, it works a bit.  I do the .conf like it says:

Nothing touching the computer and the pointer shaking across the screen--and to think my friend said touch screens were a waste on non-tablets.

So, it's my first day, I've not done much, I loose some saved passwords, a minecraft seed, nothing much.

Clean install.  Updates.

And the trackpad starts failing again.  Found another solution:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics gpointing-device-settings
```

Works for a bit, then it degrades, psmouse again.  Degrading again.

Update:

Started playing around in GIMP and it started glitching again, randomly left clicking and selecting paragraphs of text, opening up things on the taskbar.

Update:

It got so bad I disabled the touchpad

Answer (score 0):

You might try resetting the touchpad every so often using:

$ sudo tpconfig -xr

I know this is a work around, and annoying, but it isn't as bad as a flaky touchpad!